# Assign Class to CKEditor using a DIV

Tags: class, html, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in DIV mode, as compared to an IFRAME and I am attempting to assign a class to the editor itself. I have found where to add it to things within the editor, but not the editor itself. And, I would prefer to not wrap the editor within another DIV to get the effect I want.

I am also using version 4 of CKEditor.

---

Edit: The following was my questions to Reinmar after he suggested the Shared Space plugin, which at least for now I have chosen not to use.

---

Edit: In response to Reinmar I have begun using the Shared Space plugin, and do see the potential benefits of using it over a DIV.

With that said I have the following code:

```
<div id="topSpace"></div>
<textarea name="data[ArchiveQuarter][description]" class="userContent" id="editor1" cols="30" rows="6"></textarea>
```

At the bottom of the page I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        extraPlugins: 'sharedspace',
        sharedSpaces: {
            top: 'topSpace',
        }
    });
</script>
```

It currently creates the toolbar within the top space, and has the textarea, but both of them are disabled. I probably just messed up some of the configuration, but I'm not sure what.

I would greatly prefer it to use the textarea configuration as it is part of a form instead of extracting the data from inline.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in using Shared space plugin:

- [addon page](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sharedspace),
- [sample](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/sharedspace/sharedspace.html).

I'm proposing this instead of using div, because I've got mixed feelings regarding divarea plugin. Your original container is wrapped with editor's structure what changes the real context. IMO it's better to use real inline editing + the shared spaces feature to place toolbar and bottom bar where you need them.

**Update:**

When you're using inline editor, you don't need textarea. Textarea is only a data container which framed or div based editors replace with themselves.

Inline editing is all about editing real existing elements. So this can be your HTML:

```
<div id="topSpace"></div>
<div class="userContent" id="editor1"><h1>My page</h1><p>Fooo!</p></div>
```

And JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    CKEDITOR.inline( 'editor1', {
        extraPlugins: 'sharedspace',
        sharedSpaces: {
            top: 'topSpace',
        }
    } );
</script>
```

Note that I used **`CKEDITOR.inline`** not `CKEDITOR.replace`.

And the huge advantage of inline editing is that that `<div>` is a real element on your page - it is not wrapped (as in div based editor) and its contents is not moved to the frame (as in framed editor). So your content will inherit styles of your page.

The downside is that you need to implement custom data saving, because there's no form. The simplest way is to add a "save" button which clicked will send `editor.getData()` via AJAX to your server.

BTW. You probably was confused by the fact that in the [shared spaces sample](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/sharedspace/sharedspace.html) 2 editors are framed and 2 are inline. All of them reuses one top space and one bottom space.

BTW2. To make use of inline editing you don't need shared spaces in fact. Then the "floating toolbar" will be used as in here: http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline

Comment: This example here: http://vtk.ugent.be/best/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/_samples/sharedspaces.html demonstrates still using a textarea with the shared space. My textarea seems to be partially working...it is getting disabled at least. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. How can I get it properly attached?

Comment: First of all - that is CKEditor 3.x on your server. A lot has changed in 4.x (inline mode has been introduced) about which I'm talking. Although, I don't understand your problem. Please update your question with more details if that isn't just a versions difference.

Comment: Well I was really wanting to use a textarea as it is a part of a larger form. I could do an onchange type of event and then update a hidden textarea but besides using much more cpu and removing graceful degradation, it seems to really get away from my original requirement. I think for now I will just add a surrounding <div class="class"></div>. Even with the shared space I was inserting a DIV to get the toolbar where I wanted it. I appreciate you trying to help thus far, though!!

Comment: I didn't know the context, so my answer indeed does not solve your issue. It is possible to use inline editor in bigger form (and just update hidden input with the data before submit), but it doesn't make sense. Inline editing needs special approach - you should edit fragments of real page, as others see it. But in your case it may make more sense to use normal framed editor and put some work in styling contents by `contents.css` file and `config.bodyClass`. I have bad experience with div-based editor. It was a mistake that we created it in this form.